# SonarQube FindBugs analyzer (with SpotBugs 3.1.0-RC6) does not suport JDK 11

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonarqube, spotbugs

I migrated my application to OpenJDK11 and Jenkins build is failing because Findbug is no longer supported.
The plugin :

- **sonar-maven-plugin**  - *Is internally calling Findbug in java 11 env and it's breaking
  the Jenkins build*

How do I migrate this plugin to use the latest Spotbug dependency, I still want to keep the sonar-maven-plugin to get the report to sonar.

Current pom.xml relevant portion :

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0.1746</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Already went through many docs. Couldn't find a solution.

**SonarQube version:** **Version 6.7 (build 33306)**

*Installed Plugins (Relevant ones) :*

- **FindbugsExternal Analysers** Analyze Java code with [SpotBugs](https://spotbugs.github.io) 3.1.0-RC6.
  3.6.0
- **SonarJavaLanguages Code Analyzer** for Java
  5.13.1 (build 18282)
- **SonarXML Code Analyzer** for XML
  2.0.1 (build 2020)
- **CheckstyleExternal Analysers** Analyze Java code with Checkstyle
  4.23

Comment: Sry typo. It's findbug.

Comment: Add versions of the SonarQube server and installed plugins, please.

Comment: @agabrys added versions and bounty.

Answer (score 2):

> FindbugsExternal Analysers Analyze Java code with SpotBugs 3.1.0-RC6. 3.6.0

I cannot find version of the [SonarQube Findbugs](https://github.com/spotbugs/sonar-findbugs) plugin which provides SpotBugs 3.1.0-RC6. It should be between:

- [3.7.0](https://github.com/spotbugs/sonar-findbugs/releases/tag/3.7.0) (released: 15 Mar 2018) provides SpotBugs 3.1.2 (see [code](https://github.com/spotbugs/sonar-findbugs/blob/3.7.0/pom.xml#L50))
- [3.6.0](https://github.com/spotbugs/sonar-findbugs/releases/tag/3.6.0) (released: 21 Sep 2017) provides SpotBugs 3.1.0-RC5 (see [code](https://github.com/spotbugs/sonar-findbugs/blob/3.6.0/pom.xml#L50))

It seems to me that you use a custom version of the plugin.

First version of the Findbugs plugin which promise to support JDK 11 is [3.10.0](https://github.com/spotbugs/sonar-findbugs/releases/tag/3.10.0) (depends on SonarJava 5.10.1, where JDK 11 is supported since SonarJava 5.8 ([SONARJAVA-2862](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-2862)), see [code](https://github.com/spotbugs/sonar-findbugs/blob/3.10.0/pom.xml#L54)).

Second problem is that you try to use an not maintained (unsupported) version of server:

> SonarQube version: Version 6.7 (build 33306)

with the latest version of SonarScanner:

> ```
> <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
> <version>3.7.0.1746</version>
> ```

SonarQube [6.7](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/releases/tag/6.7) has been released on 8 Nov 2017 (tag has been created at 7 Nov 2017). It has been released before the first official JDK 11 LTS release (Google shows September 2018).

I think the only correct solution is to upgrade SonarQube to at least [7.9 LTS](https://www.sonarqube.org/sonarqube-7-9-lts/) with all plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading the sonar plugin version. This plugin version worked for me.

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0.1398</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```